# custom package deploy

Tags: ros, catkin-make, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like shared a custom package with a  friend but i do not want he see the code. I'm try used catkin_make install to do it but he can't run roslaunch [package] [launch file] or rosrun [package] [node] even including setup.bash o setup.sh in the install directory. Roslaunch or Rosrun found the package but not the node

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200828/custom-package-deploy/) by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After long search, I found the solution. The CMakeLists.txt file is so:

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

> project(test)

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
> roscpp
> rospy
> std_msgs
> )

> add_executable(test src/test.cpp)
> target_link_libraries(test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
> add_dependencies(test exynos_gencpp)
> add_dependencies(test ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

> install(TARGETS test
> ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
>    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
> RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
> )

> install(FILES
> launch/test.launch
> DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
> )

All right, but when I use Yaml to read file I found this error:

> Error while loading shared libraries: libyaml-cpp.so.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Any one know what is the problem?

Thanks in advanced

---

Originally posted by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) with karma: 23 on 2015-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) on 2016-11-19**:
Hi, have you solved this problem?
Please, let me know, i can't make it work on two pcs.
thanks

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2016-11-21**:
Hi, I solved my problem. Could you give me more details of your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly, ROS is a community based project. Open source code is the very heart of ROS.

Though I do not understand why you would want to share a package without the code, I push you to this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/67345/build-debian-package-locally/). But again, this is not the purpose of the local building... I asked this question to refrain from spamming the issue on the forum while I was fixing the deployment of my own package.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2015-01-13**:
The purpose is simple: my friend can' t copy the code and present it to university teacher.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-01-13**:
Ok. That's definitely a good reason. Teachers don't like copied code!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to just install your packages and then copy the install folder. Which tool are you using to build?

If `rosrun` and `roslaunch` do not work before copying the package, that is a different problem.

If they only fail after copying then make sure you source your setup.bash on the new machine before trying to use `roslaunch` and `rosrun`.

Also you'll want to make sure that the other guy has the same dependencies installed (like `rosbash` which contains the `rosrun` shell function).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2